# How to place tracking code on all pages in Ektron?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api, ektron

I need to place some javascript tracking code for Google remarketing near the footer in the body tags but I am new to Ektron and unsure of which file to access to put it into.

Answer (score 3):

Place whatever Google code you have inside the body element on your MasterPage(s).  (*.master)

If you don't have a MasterPage, create one and have each of your templates use it.  It's not difficult to swap out the html and head elements on each template and and add the MasterPageFile attribute to each Page directive.

If you have multiple MasterPages, do this for each one, or create a "master" MasterPage and then nest each existing MasterPage inside the new one.

If you'd like to give content manager's control over what is placed, add a ContentBlock server control where you want the script to go and pull in the Google code provided the ID of the ContentBlock (whatever it turns out to be).  Note: scripts will likely need to be added via the "source" view (ContentDesigner) when editing content in the Workarea to avoid the script being encoded.